# Creating a Graph from User Inputs: Web Application

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-applications

I'd like to create a web page that takes in 2 parameters from the user like X and Y co-ordinates, and then generates a graph which highlights the specified point.

- 2 text boxes for the 2 inputs and a submit button under it. (Like a form)
- On hitting submit, a Graph should be generated on the right side of the form.

How do I do it? What plugins (if any) could I use and how?

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html) is what you're looking for, head over to [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org). They have a wide range of graphs and in 2D canvas rendering...

Comment: You know... I've been such an oldschool user of RGraph, and keep seeing now mentions of ChartJS, that I'm going to have to start using that now as it looks MUCH better, and well supported.

Comment: Thumbs up, pal!